# Can I have a shared 'model' between 2 Redux states / reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example lets say I have an app that has 2 parts. One is a main area displaying information and the other is a pop up modal that lets you choose from a selection.

```
 [] [] [] [] []
 [] [] [] [] []
```

and

```
--------------
| [] [] [] [] |
| [] [] [] [] |
| [] [] [] [] |
| [] [] [] [] |
| [] [] [] [] |
---------------
```

Top is the main screen where if you select a box a modal (the bottom) pops up and lets you choose an item to place into the main screen.

The 2 areas share the same data which is a list of "heroes" to choose from.

So it is possible for these 2 "states" like "Main" and "Modal" to have the same "database" of "heroes" where they use it or something?

Like

```
const Main = {
    ...
    heroes: heroes
} 

const Modal = {
    ...
    heroes: heroes
}
```

And they both use the same "heroes" model?

Or how can I design this to work out?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't split state at all. I suggest you to have a colection of heroes and toggle a isSelected property on selection. Component props should be easily computable from such state. So if you have a selected hero you show the modal. Keeping in sync states is not the intention of redux, instead each of your view shold be able to compute needed props from a given state. Also please note that mapStateToProps receives as argument whole application state not a part of it. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Heroe list should only exist in one reducer (Main). Maybe the selected hero exist in the the Model reducer. You can inject state from multiple reducer in 1 component.

```
export default connect(
(state) => ({
    heroesList: state.main.heroesList,
    selected: state.model.selectedHero
}),
(dispatch) => ({

})
)(Model)
```

Comment: Oh ok... I think i'll try injecting both states into my components!